# Jmeter csv file for jdbc request as an input

Tags: sql, csv, jmeter

I have a question using CSV file as an input for Jmeter. Is it possible to use CSV file for storing data like select statements or update statements and then passing all that to Jmeter in JDBC request so it can execute them accordingly.

I'd appreciate any suggestion or pointing me to the right solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable from a csv file using the CSV Data Set Config http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config
Then you just need to use them in your Jdbc Sampler.

The problem here is that you must have you sql on one line.
You can also create variable from a select JDBC Sample. (See variable Names)
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.your statements need to be in different column of the CSV file.
define 2 variable names in CSV file and call them in JDBC Request file ${variable name given in CSV file}.